# self.driver.set_network_connection(1) is not working on android OS version 8 for selenium-python-client

Tags: python, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> Please find below the stack trace -
>
> **self.driver.set_network_connection(1) is working as expected for OS version 6 but having trouble with OS version 8**

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abc/Desktop/reef-py-3/testcase_web-framework/tests_student/tests/xyz.py", line 1151, in xy
    self.past_session.driver.mobile.set_network_connection(1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/mobile.py", line 64, in set_network_connection
    'parameters': {'type': mode}})['value'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
    raise wde
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 24, in check_response
    super(MobileErrorHandler, self).check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/home/abc/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=3746, uid=2000
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3507)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.sendBroadcast(Am.java:772)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:404)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)'; Code: '1'```
````